# Javascript: How do I append the label textContent after a custom span checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, frontend, mutation-observers

Looking for some help/knowledge with moving the label text to the right side of the custom checkbox instead of the left.

If you check the CodePen link below you will see that upon adding a new list item that the label text is on the wrong side of the custom checkbox. I added some hard coded list items for reference of what I want it to look like. If you have a solution to this problem please help educate me.

[CodePen: Todo List](https://codepen.io/jdubtheegreat/pen/wvxWEoV?editors=1010)

Desired HTML output

```
<li class="todo__list--item">
  <input type="checkbox" id="task-1" name="task-1" />
  <label for="task-1" class="todo__label">
    <span class="custom__checkbox"></span>
    Hard code list item #1
  </label>
  <button class="btn-del" type="button">
    <img src="../images/icon-cross.svg" alt="">
  </button>
</li>
```

JavaScript

```
const usrInput = document.getElementById('create-new');
const itemCount = document.querySelector('.item-count');

function addToList() {
  const input = document.createElement('input'); 
        input.className = 'input__cb';
        input.id = 'input';
        input.type = 'checkbox';
  const spanCB = document.createElement('span');
        spanCB.className = 'custom__checkbox';
  const label = document.createElement('label');
        label.className = 'todo__label';
        label.setAttribute('for', 'input');
        label.textContent = usrInput.value;
        label.appendChild(spanCB);
  const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meetjoewarren/learning-center/9b6cbb922ae2c81be98b6a0374bfcd08a0081e98/frontend-mentor/todo-app-main/images/icon-cross.svg';
  const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.className = 'btn-del';
        button.type = 'button';
        button.appendChild(img);
  const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.className = 'todo__list--item';
        listItem.draggable = 'true';
        listItem.appendChild(input);
        listItem.appendChild(label);
        listItem.appendChild(button);
  const details = document.querySelector('.todo__list--details'); 
  const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(listItem);
  const list = document.querySelector('.todo__list');
        list.insertBefore(fragment, details);
  itemCount.textContent = document.querySelectorAll('.todo__list--item').length;
  usrInput.value = '';
}

// Add to list on 'Enter' press
usrInput.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.code === 'Enter') {
    addToList();
  }
})


// Delete Button
const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-del');

for (let i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; i++) {
  deleteBtn[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    itemCount.textContent = document.querySelectorAll('.todo__list--item').length;
  })
}

// If checked cross out
// const inputCB = document.querySelectorAll('.input__cb');
// const todoLabel = document.querySelectorAll('.todo__label');
// for (let i = 0; i < todoLabel.length; i++) {
//   if (inputCB == true) {
//     todoLabel[i].classList.add('strikeout');
//   } else {
//     return;
//   }
// }
```

*Also, bonus question... how would I go about observing changes to the list so I can update the remove/delete button function? Mutation Observer? Right now it is only attaching the event listener to the currently hard coded list items.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox is appearing on the wrong side of the text because it is being *appended* to the end of the label, after the text. Instead of using the `appendChild()` method to do this, use the `prepend()` method. This will insert the custom checkbox before the text.

In regards to your second question, you can add attach the event listener to the delete button in your `addToList()` function, right after the element is created. Mutation Observer probably isn't what you want in this scenario.

Comment: Did not know prepend() was a thing but it definitely worked! Thanks for that!

Comment: Also, appreciate the help with the delete button. Had the loop inside the function before but it wasn't working.. only to find out it was because the variable was declared in the global and not local scope!